# CartThrob - how are orders and members linked?

Tags: cartthrob, members

Can anyone please help me to determine how CartThrob orders are linked to site members?

We are creating a custom data feed between the site and Sage for a particular project, however we are struggling to pinpoint the exact link(s) between the 3 DB tables below?

**Orders** - exp_cartthrob_order_items

**Customers** - exp_member_data

**Products** - exp_channel_data

Thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

(I'm with Vector, the company behind CartThrob).

How familiar are you with you the basic ExpressionEngine table setup? CartThrob uses standard ExpressionEngine entries to store orders and member data, so familiarity with that would help.

All orders are stored as new rows in `exp_channel_titles` and `exp_channel_data`. This has the same setup as any other ExpressionEngine entry-- metadata about the order is in `_titles` while specific custom field data is in `_data`. `exp_channel_titles.author_id` is the `member_id` of the user that placed the order. The order ID/number is the `entry_id`, which is the primary key on both tables.

If you have an order from `_data` and `_titles`, you can grab the `author_id` and look that up as the `member_id` in `exp_members` and `exp_member_data`, which are standard ExpressionEngine tables for storing member information.

And, with the order ID/`entry_id`, you can also query `exp_cartthrob_order_items` to see what specific products were ordered as part of the orders.

Let me know if you need any further information! And, feel free to [let us know](https://www.cartthrob.com/support/index.php?pg=request) if we can be of more project-specific help.

Comment: Hi Matt, the above looks great, so thank you for that. I do have experience with the EE DB structure, but I wanted to make sure the info I relay to the feed developers was 100% correct. So I'll pass this on to them and see how we get on, will let you know if we need any other info. Thanks again.